# Add Flavors to Gradle Programmatically

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project in which I am currently building 20 flavors and will likely build more than 100. The only thing that changes for each flavor is some of the resource files (drawables and strings). I would like to use gradle to walk through each folder in /src and create a flavor with the package name being com.example.dir_of_flavor based on the dir name of that flavor. Any clue how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20978525/45786