# Dynamically generating product flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've created an Android App which needs to be build in many (30+) flavors.

My idea was to generate the different `productFlavors` directly from the folder structure in my `src` directory, since the configuration is always very similar (basically just another packageName, a new launcher icon and some strings change).

The `src` folder look like this:

```
└── src
    ├── flavor1
    │   ├── flavor2.keystore
    │   ├── res
    ├── flavor2
    │   ├── res
    │   ├── flavor2.keystore    
    └── main
        ├── AndroidManifest.xml
        ├── java
        └── res
```

If I had to create the gradle properties by hand it would look somehow like this:

```
android {

    ....

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            packageName 'com.example.flavor1'
        }
        flavor2 {
            packageName 'com.example.flavor2'
        }
    }

}
```

Everytime I try to change the `productFlavors` configuration after its creation I get either an error or the changes / additions are ignored silently.
This could a be problem caused by me, because my Gradle / Groovy experience is very limited, or this isn't possible.

I mostly get error, saying that `GroupableProductFlavorDsl_Decorated` could not be manipulated the way I want.

What I'm trying to archive should somehow look like this:

```
android {

    ....

    def flavors = getMyFlavorsFromFileSystem()

    productFlavors {

    }

    flavors.each { name, config ->
        productFlavors[name] << config
    }

}
```

**Note:** I know this question is basically an [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183638/add-flavors-to-gradle-programmatically) of an older question, which sadly was never answered. Since Gradle is kind of new to the Android world, I'm hoping to get more answers as since the last time the question was asked, because more developers are using Gradle now.

**Update:**

Here some very simple approaches I tried:

**Variant 1:**

```
android {

    productFlavors {

    }

    productFlavors['flavor1'] << {
        packageName "com.example.flavor1"
    }

    productFlavors['flavor2'] << {
        packageName "com.example.flavor2"
    }
}

/*

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyProject'.
> GroupableProductFlavorDsl with name 'flavor1' not found.

*/
```

**Variant 2:**

```
android {

    productFlavors {

    }

    productFlavors['flavor1'] = {
        packageName "com.example.flavor1"
    }

    productFlavors['flavor2'] = {
        packageName "com.example.flavor2"
    }
}

/*

no error, but does not work

*/
```

**Variant 3:**

```
android {

    productFlavors {

    }

    productFlavors['flavor1'] = [packageName: "com.example.flavor1"]

    productFlavors['flavor2'] = [packageName: "com.example.flavor2"]
}

/*

no error, but does not work

*/
```

All of them as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/TheHippo/2dfe29da50a7a4fc5c3c).

Comment: "Everytime I try to mess with the productFlavors configuration I get either an error or the changes / additions are ignored silently" -- it will be very difficult to help you when you do not explain what "mess with" means, what errors you get, what the "changes / additions" are that are ignored silently, etc.

Comment: why create so many builds?  Is your code not able to recognize which build it runs on and adjust it's methods accordingly?    The Google/Android folks have done a good job in making the support libs work across flavors

Comment: @Martin I need that many builds because these apps are sold as white label applications to customers (different packageName, different Google Developer Account, diffrent keyStore). My company works in the print to web sector, so yes: I need that many builds.

Comment: (Warning: UGLY HACK) I would create a Bash script that modifies the gradle script and then builds the app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated the section of the question

Comment: "I mostly get error, saying that GroupableProductFlavorDsl_Decorated could not be manipulated the way I want" -- that was not especially useful. Your question is akin to visiting your doctor, indicating that you do not feel well, then spending 30 minutes yammering about your favorite football club without providing any symptoms. **What** are you doing **specifically** that generates errors, and what is the **complete** error output from the Gradle build?

Comment: @CommonsWare I added 3 very simple examples of what I've tried. One gives and error, the other two just don't do anything. No error, but also not `productFlavors`.

Comment: Check out my solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36294908/1957401 worked prettry well for me for mor than 300 flavors

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved by trial and error:

```
android {

    // let's assume these are return by a function which reads the filesystem
    def myFlavors = [
        flavor1: [
            packageName: "com.example.flavor1"
        ],
        flavor2: [
            packageName: "com.example.flavor2"
        ]
    ]

    productFlavors {
        myFlavors.each { name, config ->
            "$name" {
                packageName config.packageName
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that reads the filesystem to get the packageNames?

Comment: @SeanBarbeau I'd rather not. It's a little bit more complicated as I described above. (Reading directories, checking for various files, parsing some YAML and JSON...)

Comment: @TheHippo Are you still creating the `src/` folders manually or they are created somewhere else. If they are not created manually, would you mind to post that piece of code that creates the folder structure. Thx.

Comment: @danypata src folders are created by hand. They contain different app icons and custom language strings.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to accomplish the same thing. What is the $name for? (or rather, what is it? )

Comment: @hadez30 its a variable and how loops can be done in Groovy.

Comment: Thanks, TheHippo. Figured it out after posting the comment (sorry about that.) By the way, did we do the same way of getting the package name? -- from my answer, or did you accomplish it in some other way?)

Comment: Check out my solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36294908/1957401 worked prettry well for me for mor than 300 flavors

Answer (score 8):

I know there's already an answer for this, but I kind of combined Chris.Zou's approach with TheHippo. And add my own method for doing this.

Basically, when dealing with flavors, we normally work with different directories under /app/src/ which contains resources. And since the directory name is equal to the package name, I simply listed the directories under that folder (excluded "main" and "androidTest").

So here's my complete, working gradle script:

```
def map = [:]

new File("./app/src").eachFile() { file->

    def fileName = file.getName()
    if( fileName == "main" || fileName == "androidTest") {
        return
    }

    map.put(fileName, 'com.mypackagename.' + fileName )


}
productFlavors {
    map.each { flavorName, packagename ->
        "$flavorName" {
            applicationId packagename
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

- Would also like to add, the com.mypackagename is basically the root path for all flavors.
- I have a separate script that copy-pastes the a flavor directory to the /app/src/ folder.

Answer (score 4):

Since the question author didn't want to share his code for reading files. I'm gonna write about what I did. I put all the variants name in a file named "app/build_variants.txt", one line for each, something like this:

```
flavor1
flavor2
flavor3
flavor4
flavor5
```

And in "app/build.gradle":

```
//...other configs...

android {
    productFlavors {
        new File('app/build_variants.txt').eachLine { "$it" { resValue "string", "build_variant_name", "$it" } }
    }
}

//...other configs
```

This will have the same result as the following code:

```
//...other configs...

android {
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 { resValue "string", "build_variant_name", "flavor1" } 
        flavor2 { resValue "string", "build_variant_name", "flavor2" } 
        flavor3 { resValue "string", "build_variant_name", "flavor3" } 
        flavor4 { resValue "string", "build_variant_name", "flavor4" } 
        flavor5 { resValue "string", "build_variant_name", "flavor5" } 
    }
}

//...other configs
```

The key here is the line `new File('app/build_variants.txt').eachLine { "$it" { resValue "string", "build_variant_name", "$it" } }`. It reads the file 'app/build_variants.txt' and for each line, generate a product flavor with the name in the line it reads. the `$it` is the line it passes in. It just groovy's closure syntax. If you want a deeper understanding. I strongly recommend watching [@Daniel Lew's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHhf1xG0pIA) about groovy and gradle. It's awesome!.

Comment: Question was about how to generate flavor dynamically and not about how to read a file from a gradle build script.

Comment: @TheHippo My answer also include the code to generate flavor dynamically, plus the code for reading a file, which may be help for people who whats to keep their product flavors in a separate file.

Comment: what if each line contains comma separated multiple values. How can i split and put them seperately in the generated flavors? In your example you are putting the whole line (which is just the flavor name). Which worked for me. But i want to pass along the application id and the resValues as well from the file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very late but may be useful to someone.
We have **200+ flavors** and we manage them by only one .json file with dynamic flavors.

1. Create *keystores* and *projects_info* folders inside app folder. Now create `projects_info.json` file inside projects_info folder and insert information for every flavor.

- Put KeyStore file(s) in keystores folder.
- Create different flavors folders in `src` folder and put respected code/resources.

```
{
  "projectsInfoJSONArray": [
    {
      "projectVariantName": "project1",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "versionName": "1.0",
      "applicationId": "com.project1",
      "storeFile": "keystores/MyKeyStore1.jks",
      "storePassword": "yourStorePassword",
      "keyAlias": "yourKeyAlias",
      "keyPassword": "yourKeyPassword",
      "isLive": 1
    },
    {
      "projectVariantName": "project2",
      "versionCode": 2,
      "versionName": "1.2",
      "applicationId": "com.project2",
      "storeFile": "keystores/MyKeyStore2.jks",
      "storePassword": "yourStorePassword",
      "keyAlias": "yourKeyAlias",
      "keyPassword": "yourKeyPassword",
      "isLive": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Add this code into app level `build.gradle` file. And sync project with gradle.

```
def applicationDefinitions = []

def projectsInfoFile = file('projects_info/projects_info.json')
def projectsInfoJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(projectsInfoFile.text)
def projectsInfoArray = projectsInfoJSON.projectsInfoJSONArray
def projectsInfoMap = [:]
projectsInfoArray.each { projectInfo ->
    projectsInfoMap[projectInfo.projectVariantName] = projectInfo

    applicationDefinitions.add(['name': projectInfo.projectVariantName, 'applicationId': projectInfo.applicationId])
}

applicationDefinitions.each { applicationDefinition ->
    def signingConfig = projectsInfoMap[applicationDefinition['name']]
    if (signingConfig.isLive == 1) android.productFlavors.create(applicationDefinition['name'], { flavor ->
        flavor.applicationId = applicationDefinition['applicationId']
        flavor.versionCode = signingConfig.versionCode
        flavor.versionName = signingConfig.versionName

        flavor.signingConfig = android.signingConfigs.create(applicationDefinition['name'])
        flavor.signingConfig.storeFile = file(signingConfig.storeFile)
        flavor.signingConfig.storePassword = signingConfig.storePassword
        flavor.signingConfig.keyAlias = signingConfig.keyAlias
        flavor.signingConfig.keyPassword = signingConfig.keyPassword
    }) else println "===> " + signingConfig.projectVariantName + " is Not LIVE. Excluding it from build."
}
```

- You can have a look at this [GitHub sample code.](https://github.com/RumitPatel/android-dynamic-flavours)