# google-services.json causing problems in creating product flavors of my app, possible fix?

Tags: android, json, gradle, google-play-services

I am working on an app that needs two productFlavors, so I modified my gradle file this way:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId = "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.free"
    }

    paid {
        applicationId = "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid"
    }
}
```

Now since I use Google Ads inside my app, they provided the `google-services.json` file, now this is causing a lot of trouble.
Since this is not something new, I tried this [thread](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54).

And I modified my dependencies to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Now the **problem** is , when i sync the gradle file, respective directories for free and the paid versions are not created, also, I get an error

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processPaidReleaseGoogleServices'.
>
> > No matching client found for package name 'com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid'

above which Parsing json file:`D:\ud867\FinalProject\app\google-services.json` failed.

Now, if anyone experienced similar problem, please do share the fix you applied to solve the problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you already modified your json file this way:

```
app/src/
flavor1/google-services.json
flavor2/google-services.json
...
```

as discussed in [Adding the JSON File](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file).

Modifying your gradle file in the following format:

```
android {

    def myFlavors = [
        flavor1: [
            packageName: "com.example.flavor1"
        ],
        flavor2: [
            packageName: "com.example.flavor2"
        ]
    ]

    productFlavors {
        myFlavors.each { name, config ->
            "$name" {
                packageName config.packageName
            }
        }
    }

}
```

as given in this SO post - [Dynamically generating product flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976946/dynamically-generating-product-flavors) might help.