# Android app flavor name as a variable instead of static string

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-build-flavors, android-flavors

I have been trying for the past hour to set some variable name like FLAVOR_NAME in gradle.properties and then use that in build.gradle to have a sort of a dynamic flavor name. No success yet. Is it even possible to have a dynamic flavor name? I mean something like:

```
$FLAVOR_NAME{
     versionName FLAVOR_VERSION
     versionCode FLAVOR_CODE
}
```

Comment: Probably not with that syntax, but there should be some way in the DSL to call a method that adds a flavor based upon a variable. Or, consider your `build.gradle` to be output of something else that code-generates the file, so your variables are in your code generator, not `build.gradle` itself.

Comment: @Eloy_007 would you mind pasting what you have for a `build.gradle` file?  While flavorNames aren't really dynamic*, the [buildVariant](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) can be constructed from multiple flavor names.

Comment: Ah nevermind I ended up using bash scripts that dynamically replace all these names for me. It kind of sucks that Gradle plugin doesn't support that (at least for what I could tell)

Comment: Eloy_007 checkout the provided answer... i think this may get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Eloy_007,

While your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976946/dynamically-generating-product-flavors), there are some nuances in your question that I think the following will answer.

First off, there is a [great article that you should read](http://seaplain.com/2015/10/21/improving-gradle-flavours.html) where the author(Coby Plain) goes about providing a better framework for working with flavors.  Also, the [android10/Android-CleanArchitecture repo](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) has a really nice structure for importing gradle properties. Look in `buildsystem/dependencies.gradle` and `presentation/build.gradle` for guidance.

That said, here's a quick sample of what importing properties looks like when working with *semi-dynamic/imported* flavors:

In the gradle file, we can reference an external file that has all of our related properties defined together and maybe use some simple groovy magic to join strings etc.

`build.gradle:`

```
apply from: "properties.gradle" // load in properties from some other file

// ... plugins, etc.

android {
    // some other sections
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            // you may want to keep some non-imported flavors.
            // maybe you're working with flavor dimension here
        }

        // ... maybe more standard flavors

        flavors.each {name, flavor -> 
            def wrapEscaped = { s -> "\"${s}\""} // simple function to wrap strings
            "$name" {
                applicationId flavor.applicationId
                versionName "${some_version_number}"

                buildConfigField "String", "MAJOR_KEY", wrapEscaped(flavor.majorKey)
                buildConfigField "String", "ANOTHER_ONE", wrapEscaped(flavor.anotherOne)
                buildConfigField "int", "PILLOW_COUNT", flavor.pillowCount

                // ... additional configs
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the referenced `properties.gradle` you define `flavors` as follows:

```
ext {
  config = [
      baseId : "io.wethebest.mobile"
  ]

  flavors = [
      free    : [
          applicationId: config.baseId + ".free",
          majorKey     : "COCOA BUTTER",
          anotherOne   : "ANOTHER ONE",
          pillowCount  : 1,
      ]
      simple : [
          applicationId: config.baseId + ".simple",
          majorKey     : "A HAMMOCK",
          anotherOne   : "ANOTHER ONE",
          pillowCount  : 10,
      ],
      paid   : [
          applicationId: config.baseId,
          majorKey     : "A JETSKI",
          anotherOne   : "ANOTHER ONE",
          pillowCount  : 100000000,
      ]
  ]
}
```

At a minimum, this allows for you define your flavors **outside** of your `build.gradle` file so that you can minimze the amount of cruft you have to sift through. Plus, major key, it keeps the revision history for the `build.gradle` file clean.

HTH, Good Luck!